# Java Base64 encoding of a text

Tags: java, php, encoding, base64

I'm trying to use texts Base64 encoding but unfortunately i've got some problems with it.

```
<?php

/* Insert data */

$data = '#';

/* Insert code */

$string = str_replace(chr(35), $data, base64_decode($data));

echo hash("sha1", $string);
echo '<br>';
echo hash_file("sha1", "quine.php");

class Prova{

    public static function sum($a, $b){
        return $a+$b;
    }

}

?>
```

When i try to encode the above text with java i use the following commands

```
try {

        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(write_path);

        ArrayList<String> file_lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line, lineToEncode = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            file_lines.add(line);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < file_lines.size() - 1; i++) {
            lineToEncode += file_lines.get(i) + "\n";
        }

        lineToEncode += file_lines.get(file_lines.size() - 1);

        // System.out.print(lineToEncode);

        String encodedLine = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(lineToEncode.getBytes());
        System.out.println(encodedLine);
```

Also, i used an online (https://www.base64encode.org/) base64 encoder to get a proof that my method works and computes the right encoded string. It turns out that the two method does not outputs the same results indeed the two encoded strings differ from each other.
However, in the php module i use the base64_decode() function which works well only when i use the online encoded string, indeed it decodes the right string. Therefore, i suppose that the problem is that java and php econding/decoding differ. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Look into using ByteArrayInputStream instead of BufferedReader. Adding your own \n might result in a string that is not identical to the file.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, your solution works!